# Energy required to transfer air from one cylinder to other

Tags: thermodynamics

Consider one cube meter air is kept in a cylinder at pressure 70 bar. This cylinder is connected with another cylinder with zero volume. If load on the piston of second cylinder is equal to 70 bar then what will be the amount of energy needed to transfer the air from first cylinder to second cylinder in one minute? The pressure in the pipe that connect both cylinders is also 70 bar.

Comment: Welcome to physics.SE. Please note that this is *not* a homework help site. Homework-like questions must ask about the *concepts* involved in the task. As it stands the question fails our requirement and will likely be closed. Please consider reading [the FAQ on homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) for more information.